# How to redirect to full image view page by clicking a thumbnail in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web-applications

I have a asp page home.aspx which have many thumbnails . Each thumbnail is in Image Button.
I want that if user clicks the thumbnail the user should be redirected to Details.aspx which has the full size image and description about the item.

My approach is 
When user click the thumbnail, click event stores the image name in a session and redirects to Details.aspx

Now the Details.aspx sets the image control's url by taking the name from session...

Plz tell me that is it a good approach .. if not... then suggest me anyother...
If yes then plz tell me how can i store image name in session..
My image url is "~thumbnails/image1.jpg"

How can i get image name only like "image1.jpg" from url string and store it to seasion..

Thanks